# ¿Como puedo reproducir varios vídeos en un videoview en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, video

Tengo 21 botones y quiero que con cada uno se reproduzca un vídeo diferente, este es el código que uso para reproducir videos pero solo puedo reproducir un video, ¿como puedo condicionar cada boton para que reproduzca un vídeo distinto? ¿o existe otra forma de hacerlo?

```
public class ActivityPrueba extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prueba);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });


//  AQUI EMPIEZA EL REPRODUCTOR DE MUSICA 
    Button buttonPlayVideo2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnP_LCD);
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
//displays a video file
    buttonPlayVideo2.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            VideoView mVideoView2 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView9);
// VideoView mVideoView = new VideoView(this);
            String uriPath = "android.resource://com.example.dante.provantf_movil/" + R.raw.controlv8;
            Uri uri2 = Uri.parse(uriPath);
            mVideoView2.setVideoURI(uri2);
            mVideoView2.requestFocus();
            mVideoView2.start();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: si tienes 21 botones, solo debes agregarle la funcionalidad a cada botón, como lo haces con uno, debes hacerlo con todos, solo que cada uno tendra sus parametros

Comment: Eso hice y funciona, pero se nota una ligera distorsión al momento de cambiar entre vídeos.

Comment: Es obvio, si cargas multimedia y dependiendo del tamaño de tu video, puede ser mas o menos rapido, debes tomar en cuenta eso. Asi como al cargar imagenes debes regular su forma de cargarlas para que no se coloque lenta la app

Comment: Son vídeos que pesan entre 1 a 3 MB, ¿Aun así es normal?

Comment: ¿Es posible almacenar en un Switch los vídeos para posteriormente utilizarlo?

Comment: puedes usar un case, depende como tu lo quieras hacer.